# Check if vectors contains numbers with certain length

Tags: r, vector, numbers

In R, say I have a vector

`myvec <- c(123, a33, 164, 9234, 1)`

I want to check if the vector values are 3-digit numbers, so that I get the output

`TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE`

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: `nchar(myvec) == 3`.

Comment: If `a33` means a character string, you should surround it with quote marks. Otherwise it throws an error: `Error: object 'a33' not found`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to find a specific expression.

The following code using `grepl` function will test for each values of vector `x`, the pattern starting `^` and ending `$` with 3 `{3}` digits `[0-9]`.

```
x <- c(123, 'a33', 164, 9234, 1)
grepl(pattern="^[0-9]{3}$", x=x)
```

Comment: Made a small update since `grep` returns either values or vector position of TRUE expressions. `grepl` returns a `TRUE/FALSE` boolean

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use `parse_number()` to extract the numbers and then count `nchar()`. This additional step is necessary if you have the case like the last entry "b345".

```
x <- c(123, 'a33', 164, 9234, 1, 'b345')
nchar(readr::parse_number(x)) == 3
```

**Output**

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```